# AsyncPostBackTrigger and PostBackTrigger in AJAX?

Tags: .net, ajax

What is the difference and when would you use one and not the other?

Answer (score 0):

http://ramanisandeep.wordpress.com/2009/04/07/asyncpostbacktrigger-vs-postbacktrigger/..check this site.it's explained with examples..